# Ring Homomorphisms from a ring R to a ring S.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The book I am using for my Abstract Algebra course is Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Joseph A. Gallian.

> Find the rings $R$, $S$ as below. There is a ring homomorphism from a ring $R$ to a ring $S\neq \{0\}$, so that $R$ has a unity but $S$ does not.

Do I just need to given an example of a ring homomorphism $\phi:R\rightarrow S$ where $R$ has identity under multiplication but not $S$? Is there more to this question that I am not understanding?

---

Sorry for the rather short question. I sincerely thank you for taking the time to read this post. I greatly appreciate any assistance you may provide.

Comment: Yes. You understood the question correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gallian define rings without the necessity of unit in them, so you see $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{2Z}$ both are rings, so just look for a ring homomorphism between them. Looks pretty obvious as $\mathbb{2Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$